# please rebuild precompiled header error when building inet project

Tags: omnet++, veins, inet

I'm working with inet and veins in omnet++, when I build inet project, there is always an error like the following in the console:

```
please rebuild precompiled header 'inet/common/precompiled_debug.h.pch'
```

I can not understand how to solve the error. I tried to run ./configure then make clean and make. However the error still exists. I appreciate if anyone can guid me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make cleanall` should solve that, but simply deleting the `inet/common/precompiled_debug.h.pch` file will also solve the problem.